# Where can I find a free, interesting web service with near real-time data updates?

Tags: web-services

I'm looking for a web service that provides the following:

1. Free public access,
2. Real-time updates (or near-RT),
3. Location-based information (preferably latitude & longitude but street address / city could work),
4. The data is interesting with a reason for RT updates. For example, live earthquake feeds showing earthquake data as it happens.

I'd like a web service like this for an upcoming proof of concept project. I would like to consume an existing service for various reasons. I know I could roll my own service but there has to be something out there readily available from a government agency.

Any suggestions? Keep in mind, my proof of concept is not about the data so the web service could be for anything. Public health incidents, earthquakes, weather, traffic accidents, crime, etc as long as the service is updated frequently. I'm not looking for a service that gives me a list of all the states and largest cities as this is a fairly static dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this list of web-services](http://www.xmethods.com/ve2/Directory.po) (http://www.xmethods.com/ve2/Directory.po) has something for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Yahoo has something you can use available through [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's streaming API is probably the best you'll do, huge corpus of data that's delivered in real-time.  http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Streaming-API-Documentation